# Bundle is loaded in the wrong order

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, bundle, bundling-and-minification

In my _Layout view I'm including the following scriptbundle:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/js").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery.min.js",
                "~/Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js",
                "~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js",
                "~/Scripts/jquery.flot.categories.js",
                "~/Scripts/jquery.flot.js",
                "~/Scripts/jquery.flot.min.js",
                "~/Scripts/jquery.flot.orderBars.js",
                "~/Scripts/jquery.flot.pie.js",
                "~/Scripts/jquery.flot.resize.js",
                "~/Scripts/graphtable.js",
                "~/Scripts/fullcalendar.min.js",
                "~/Scripts/chosen.jquery.min.js",
                "~/Scripts/autoresize.jquery.min.js",
                "~/Scripts/jquery.autotab.js",
                "~/Scripts/jquery.jgrowl_minimized.js",
                "~/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.min.js",
                "~/Scripts/jquery.stepy.min.js",
                "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js",
                "~/Scripts/jquery.cookie.js",
                "~/Scripts/raphael.2.1.0.min.js",
                "~/Scripts/justgage.1.0.1.min.js",
                "~/Scripts/glisse.js",
                "~/Scripts/styleswitcher.js",
                "~/Scripts/moderniz.js",
                "~/Scripts/jquery.sparkline.min.js",
                "~/Scripts/slidernav-min.js",
                "~/Scripts/jquery.fancybox.js",
                "~/Scripts/main.js",
                "~/Scripts/application.js",
                "~/Scripts/excanvas.min.js",
                "~/Scripts/float.settings.infobox.js"
            ));
```

The thing is; when I load the page and look at the network traffic I see that jquery-ui.min.js is loaded first (before jquery.min.js)!

Here is the order in which they load in:
[image]

I thought the scripts would load in the order I specified them in. Am I wrong? And if so, how should I load them in the proper order?

EDIT:
I tried adding a custom sort as described here: 
http://stevescodingblog.co.uk/changing-the-ordering-for-single-bundles-in-asp-net-4/

However I get the following error when building the project:
Error   1   'Namespace.AsIsBundleOrderer' does not implement interface member 'System.Web.Optimization.IBundleOrderer.OrderFiles(System.Web.Optimization.BundleContext, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable)'

Comment: It may be bundling in the order in which the files are in the Scripts folder.

Comment: @RayEatmon
The scripts are autosorted alphabetically in my scripts folder.
However shoudln't I be able to sort them in a custom manner like I tried above?

Comment: @JamieRomeo even if you specify order, it will move known libraries around, and as such it should definitely be putting jQuery first. Can you please post the HTML for the script refs? Also, as for your other error, this is due to a recent update in the bundle package. In the method, `IEnumerable<FileInfo>` has been replaced with `IEnumerable<BundleFile>`.

Comment: I have this *exact* problem, jquery and jquery-ui being loaded in the wrong order. In my project this occurs as soon as I add jquery-ui to the vendor bundle created by the project template. Thus the only HTML involvement is `@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/vendor")` in the default index.cshtml file.

Comment: Creating a separate bundle and using two `@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/bundlename")` statements *didn't work* much to my surprise. This thing appears to be flat out broken. How can they not know this? jQuery-UI is extremely common! If there is a workaround other than manual bundling of jQuery and jQuery-UI, I hope someone posts it.

Answer (score 0):

Some things that can cause this problem:

- Buggy version of ASP.NET Web Optimization Framework. Update to 1.1.3 or later.
- Explicit names are always processed before symbolic names.

### Explicitly named dependent of symbolically named libraries

Knockout-jqueryui.js doesn't have a version in its name. It depends on jQuery and jQuery UI. Both of these have versions in their names. If you use symbolic names like jQuery-{version} to refer to these libraries, because knockout-jqueryui is named explicitly, it will be loaded in the first pass - before its dependencies.

Either name the versions explicitly or fudge a version number into the dependent library name and make them all symbolic.